# How to remove auto-generated meta description from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

Can anyone help me remove auto generated meta description from my wordpress website?

website name is bharatdetails.com (a blog website)

One meta description is generated by Rank Math and I am unable to identify the second meta description generator. I want to remove the second meta description that is being generated automatically.

please help me with the steps to be followed to remove multiple meta description tag from website

I tried using multiple plugins to remove auto generated content. But ths did't work.

Comment: Did you already take a look at the theme.s header.php? It might be in there...